# In or out ...does not make difference

Tags: word

Which eight lettered English word means almost the same and remains of the same part of speech though one letter is removed from it?

The word of interest is an adjective. It is neither a verb of continuous tense, nor past tense, nor present tense.

Comment: Do we remove any letter or a letter from a specific position?

Comment: Without clues to solve, this is simply language trivia.

Comment: Coloured and Colored ;).

Comment: There are lots of words with alternate spellings that would fit the question (e.g. flavours/flavors), though I'm sure that isn't the intention.  (Edit: Ninja'd by a few seconds there)

Comment: Well, @ Sid -- removal of a letter, from a specific location.  LiefdeWen... Good attempt, but no need to distinguish between English of UK / US / Any other nation. Both are in the same form of English usage. The same is applicable  Jaap S...s

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Is it Envelope?

Comment: @LiefdeWen, nope, this is not a tricky question, but a serious one :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually many words that fit.  Most of them are alternate-spelling pairs (*e.g., COLOURED/COLORED, DAEMONIC/DEMONIC*) so I won't include them.

Here are a few:

> BLEEPING / BEEPING 
>  CRUMPLED / RUMPLED 
>  ERADIATE / RADIATE 
>  MUTTERED / UTTERED ([credit to Sp3000](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38773699#38773699)) 
>  SCRAPPED / SCRAPED 
>  SMASHING / MASHING 
>  SPLUTTER / SPUTTER ([credit to Sp3000](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38773699#38773699))

Edit: Given the new information in the comments (which *should* have been in the question), the expected word may be

> AMICABLE / AMIABLE

...However, even though these words are similar, they are not truly synonyms, and should not be used interchangeably.

Comment: Well, @Mike Q, the word of interest is  neither a verb of continuous tense nor past tense nor present temse. It is an adjective. Perhaps this is the clue for those who are interested and requested. Spoiler formatting not good at I am !

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That information is crucial to finding your answer, and so it should be in the question.

Comment: How about inhumane and inhuman? That's an adjective, I think

Comment: @Mike Q, got it. So accordingly my edits. Here is a hint (#1): First three letters of it are the same as that of its Spanish counterpart, though a noun form in Spanish, my dear 'friend' !

Comment: Yes, @Sid, you got one such word ! Correct !!

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That is not a hint. That is an important requirement for the answer, and should be part of the puzzle itself. How else was I supposed to know about the first three letters?  That seems like a new rule, and is unfair. *All* of the requirements should be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @MikeQ the last one is correct !